# C++ Dynamic Array allocation in Classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am currently learning basics of c++, and am coming across an issue with the class array below.

```
class Arrayclass {
private:
    int arraySize;
    float array[];

public:
    Arrayclass(int arraySize) {
        float * array = new float[arraySize]();
}

~Arrayclass() {
   delete[] array;
}
}
```

As far as I am aware, I am having issues with the array being initialized in the constructor not actually corresponding to a stored array in the new class, thus when I am initializing a new class in my main, the array created holds 0 values. I apologize my explanation is unclear, just trying to understand how the array initialized in the constructor correlates to the array in my private.

Comment: You're declaring a local variable `array` in the constructor, it has nothing to do with the data member `array`. Just put `array = new float[arraySize]();` in the constructor.

Comment: It doesn't help that your constructor defines a new variable named `array` that has no relationship whatsoever to the class member named `array`  - and ceases to exist when the constructor returns. Instead, initialise the `array` member in the constructor initialiser list (not in the constructor body)  i.e. `ArrayClass(int  arraySize) : array(new float[arraySize] {};`. Also, classes that manage a resource (like a dynamically allocated array, in your case) usually need to manually implement copy constructors, copy assignment, and destructors.  Look up "rule of three" for information on that.

Comment: `float array[];` is not allowed in Standard C++. Maybe you meant `float * array;`, but you should have used `std::vector<float> array;`

Answer (score 3):

> `float array[]`

either is an extension or just doesn't compile. For a C-style static array, `Type name[constexpr_size]` is used. For a dynamic array, `Type* name` is stored as a pointer to the beginning of the storage allocated.

> Dynamic Array

OK, we need the second option. Then, we start with your snippet

```
class Array { // "class Arrayclass" -> "class Array", no need to repeat ourselves
private:
    float* array{};
    int size{}; // "Array::arraySize" -> "Array::size", again
public:
    ~Array() { delete[] array; } // your destructor is fine
};
```

(see [member initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18811798/12816539) as an explanation to those `{}` initializers in `float* array{}` and `int size{}`).

What about

> `Arrayclass(int arraySize) { float * array = new float[arraySize](); }`

, you create a local `float*` which dies at the end of scope (=the constructor). You probably meant to store that `new`ly allocated array in (`this->`)`array`:

```
Array(int newSize) { // BAD CODE, see below
    array = new float[newSize]{};
    size = newSize;
}
```

but the code above is like writing `float* p; p = something` (create default, than initialize it) instead of `float* p{something}` (initialize on creation), let's improve it by using [member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8523361/12816539):

```
Array(int newSize): array{new float[newSize]{}}, size{newSize} {}
```

Now, your array (almost) can construct and destruct properly.

==========

However, there's still an issue left: code such as

```
{
    Array a1{42};
    Array a2{a1}; // copy construction
}
```

has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581132/12816539) and in practice (in this case) should/might crash your application. Why? Because it works as something like (`size`s omitted):

```
{
    float* array1{new float[42]{}};
    float* array2{array1};
    delete[] array1;
    delete[] array2; // that UB (double free); the same dynamic array is deleted twice
}
```

Well, it is a topic for another "lesson". See [the rule of three (five) (zero)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/12816539). In general, see RAII and copy/move-semantics.

Comment: "should crash your application" -> "has undefined behaviour". You are *lucky* when that manifests as "crash your application"

Comment: @Caleth added this.