# build error using Custom data types with Thrust Vectors and Cuda

Tags: c++, constructor, cuda, thrust

I am using Thrust vectors for cuda kernels and i have created my own struct so i can pass in all of the data together, when i initialise a host vector of my custom type i get a build error from thrust.

initialisation of the vector:

```
host_vector<PhysicsData> physicsDataVector(numPeople + 1, 0);
```

custom data type:

```
__device__ __host__ struct PhysicsData {
    vector3 position;
    vector3 velocity;
    vector3 acceleration;
    vector3 force;
    float massInvert = 1.f;
    float drag = 1.f;
    bool dead = false;

    __device__ __host__ PhysicsData(){
        massInvert = 1.f;
        drag = 1.f;
        dead = false;
        position = vector3();
        velocity = vector3();
        acceleration = vector3();
        force = vector3();
    };
};
```

Error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'void thrust::detail::vector_base<T,Alloc>::fill_init(unsigned __int64,const T &)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'IteratorOrIntegralType' to 'const T &'  DefinitelyNotGodzillaCuda   C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.7\include\thrust\detail\vector_base.inl  208
```

Comment: There is no implicit conversion from `int` to `PhysicsData`. The problem has nothing to do with either Cuda or Thrust. (Also, look in the Output window instead of the Error List to see the entire error message.)

Comment: Side note: your constructor only repeats what the default initialization has already done.

Comment: FYI: While Thrust explicitly supports the use of custom types, this kind of usage will give you very bad performance due to strided memory access. For good [coalescing of global memory accesses](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) you want a struct-of-array (SoA) data layout, i.e. one vector for each data-member of `PhysicsData` or maybe even for each component of `vector3`. See also [Using thrust to handle vectors in CUDA classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74171258/10107454).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was I was using the wrong constructor for the vector, I for some reason had a `, 0` in my constructor so changing it to this fixed it

```
physicsDataVector(numPeople + 1);
```